# ToggleButtons in android

Tags: android, android-togglebutton

Hey guys I have a layout containing 4 toggle buttons.The first one is always enabled or is switched on.When I enable the second one,the remaining three should be switched off or disabled automatically.Same goes with the other remaining two.At once,only one switch should be on.

I made a function for this using toggle buttons setchecked(boolean flag) by setting it to true or false.But the buttons do not change their state dynamically.

this is the method..

```
public void setChoicesStates(boolean nameToggle,boolean surnameToggle,boolean emailToggle,boolean groupToggle )
    {
        mNameToggle.setChecked(nameToggle);
        mSurnameToggle.setChecked(surnameToggle);
        mEmailToggle.setChecked(emailToggle);
        mGroupToggle.setChecked(groupToggle);
    }
```

and then set the state to true or false in the check changed listener assigned to the toggle buttons.
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: you can test with "buttonToToggle.toggle();"

Answer (score 1):

Use an:

```
setOnCheckedChangeListener()
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html

Comment: I have used the check changed listener..and my method worked.thanks a lot.just needed to call the method at the right place.thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
ToggleButton tb1, tb2, tb3, tb4;
tb1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
        tb2 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton2);
        tb3 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton3);
        tb4 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton4);
        tb1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (tb1.isChecked()) {
                    tb2.setChecked(false);
                    tb3.setChecked(false);
                    tb4.setChecked(false);

                }
            }
        });
        tb2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (tb2.isChecked()) {
                    tb1.setChecked(false);
                    tb3.setChecked(false);
                    tb4.setChecked(false);

                }
            }
        });
        tb3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (tb3.isChecked()) {
                    tb1.setChecked(false);
                    tb2.setChecked(false);
                    tb4.setChecked(false);

                }
            }
        });
        tb4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (tb4.isChecked()) {
                    tb2.setChecked(false);
                    tb3.setChecked(false);
                    tb1.setChecked(false);

                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: I have used the check changed listener..and my method worked.thanks a lot.just needed to call the method at the right place.thanks.But I will try out this one as well.Will have a look at which one is better.